# Program is being executed differently

Tags: process, gnome, users, sublime-text

I'm executin Sublime Text 3 by `terminal` on GNOME like so:

```
# subl
```

and I execute the program by the left tab in GNOME too. <-- there. The same program.
But I'm getting different settings. In a program I have a installed plugin but in other program(sublime) I don't have that plugin, and the interface is different.
Below are my process:

```
user@debian:~$ ps aux | grep subl
user     29388  2.3  1.8 821400 56020 tty2     Sl+  00:28   0:01 /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
user     29400  0.6  0.6 118792 19100 tty2     Sl+  00:28   0:00 /opt/sublime_text/plugin_host 29388
root     29411  2.5  2.0 938104 61548 ?        Ssl  00:28   0:01 /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
root     29422  1.1  0.8 201492 26336 ?        Sl   00:28   0:00 /opt/sublime_text/plugin_host 29411
user     29452  0.0  0.0  12784   936 pts/0    S+   00:29   0:00 grep subl
user@debian:~$
```

> How I get the same interface(program) using different ways to access it ?

Comment: run as the same user; `root` or `user`

Comment: Has a way to merge all users to use the same program ? @IporSircer

Comment: They're already use the same program, `/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text`. The config files are different.

Comment: @IporSircer So in this way I need to put `~/.config/sublime` in root ?